# Gridgain 6.5.5 OpenSource - Multiple nodes are slower..?

Tags: java, gridgain

I downloaded the open source version of Gridgain 6.5.5 and I am trying out the examples bundled with the release on my Windows desktop.

The scenarios are as below:

I run the example org.gridgain.examples.compute.ComputeCallableExample with a 4500 character string with the VM arguments `-Xmx1g -Xms512m` and it computes in **262 milliseconds**.

I start a grid node with the below command `ggstart.bat %GRIDGAIN_HOME%\examples\config\example-compute.xml` and then run the ComputeCallableExample and it computes in **1039 milliseconds**.

When I pre start 2 nodes and then run the example it even takes more time **1196 milliseconds**

My questions are as follows:

1. Is this expected behavior? Shouldn't the computations take less time with more nodes available to process?
2. Am I missing something in any configurations? Examples I mention can be found here
3. How can I improve this behavior?
4. What are the minimum system requirements for running an gridgain application with atleast 2 nodes?

Answer (score 0):

There are several factors that may affect the result:

1. This example splits a string into words and distributes the words among nodes. Does your string have multiple words of approximately equal size?
2. Two nodes will definitely be slower than one because you are adding a network trip. Generally, if you are able to execute something locally, it will always be faster. You add more nodes to ensure that jobs will be failed over in case of a crash, or when you have more computations than can be handled by one node.
3. Timing just one execution is not a good benchmark because JVMs need some warm up time. Can you put your execution in a loop and execute it for a couple of minutes? I believe the performance numbers will improve.